# Boxplots in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

My goal is to visualize some data frames with `ggplot2`.

I have several data.frames looking like this

[image]

And my goal is a boxplot looking like this, just nicer.

[image]

I managed to get single boxplots using

```
plt <- ggplot(data, aes(RF, data$RF)) +
  geom_boxplot()
plt
```

But that's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
airquality_m = melt(airquality)
ggplot(airquality_m, aes(variable, value )) + geom_boxplot()
```

I did not *beautify* the plot but I guess you get the idea here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That boxplot you showed is created with base-r graphics. Single command

`boxplot(data)` will do it.

If you want to use `ggplot`, you have to first `melt` the dataframe and then plot.

```
library(reshape2)
datPlot <- melt(data)
ggplot(datPlot,aes(variable,value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Yea I did that obviously ("my goal is a boxplot looking like this just nicer). But I want them with ggplot2 since the basic boxplot function does not look very good.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
myddt_m = melt(mydata)
names(myddt_m)=c("Models","CI")
ggplot(myddt_m, aes(Models, CI,fill=Models )) + geom_boxplot()+guides(fill=FALSE)+labs( x="", y="C-Index")
```

[image: The resulting image]