# boxplot equivalent in ggplot 2 + advise for outlier detection and normality

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample:

```
ex <- structure(list(Q1 = c(2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1, 
6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6, 1, 5, 4, 6, 
6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 
7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6), Q2 = c(2, 
4, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 3, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 7, 4, 
2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q3 = c(6, 
7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 7, 5, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 5, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6), Q4 = c(1, 
6, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6, 4, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 
2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4), Q5 = c(2, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 6, 6, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5, 
4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4, 7, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1, 6, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 6), Q6 = c(6, 
7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5, 
2, 7, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 
2, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 6, 3, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried

```
boxplot(ex)
```

and it gives me a very rough boxplot.

My questions are:

1. What would be the ggplot equivalent to get the graph/ an improved version (or the same for that matter, I just want the ggplot code to generate it).
2. Is there an R function that can give me an elegant report of both normality and outliers, both graphically and in table form (NA's would be nice too, but I have none in the sample sent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boxplots in ggplot2 R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046242/boxplots-in-ggplot2-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1: ggplot boxplot**

First bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer` then use `geom_boxplot()`

```
ex_long <- ex %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  )

ggplot(ex_long, aes(x = names, y=values)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

**Question 2a: Visual and tabular check for normality:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

library("ggpubr")
# Visual check for normality
# Density plot
ggdensity(ex_long$values, fill = "blue")
# QQ plot
ggqqplot(ex_long$values)

# tabular p values for shapiro test
ex_long %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  shapiro_test(values)
```

**Question 2b Outliers:**

```
# set limits of outliers with the percentile method
lower_bound <- quantile(ex_long$values, 0.025)
lower_bound
upper_bound <- quantile(ex_long$values, 0.975)
upper_bound

# Identify all outlieres
outlier_ind <- which(ex_long$values < lower_bound | ex_long$values > upper_bound)
outlier_ind

# print table
ex[outlier_ind, "values"]


# test for outliers with the grubbs test
# install.packages("outliers")
library(outliers)
test <- grubbs.test(ex_long$values)
test

# visualise outliers with `mtext` in ggplot

ggplot(ex_long, aes(x = names, y=values)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  mtext(paste("Outliers: ", paste(out, collapse = ", ")))
```

**Conclusion**
Your data is not normally distributed and you do not have any outliers!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer to your first question -

`ggplot` prefers the data in long format which can be done using `pivot_longer`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]